# Htaccess: how to redirect Urls?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-alias

I have an issue with a website that I am currently trying to redirect. The client wants the home page to be redirected to one website, and all other website pages to another website. It is an e-commerce site. I know how to redirect just the home page to a specific page

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://www.new-website.com/
```

but I cannot find how to redirect all pages excluding the home page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://site1.com/
RedirectMatch ^/(.+)$ http://site2.com/$1
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, can I ask, what does the $1 do after site2.com?

Comment: @Andy $1 is a backrefrence it contains the  uri string we captured in **(.+)** eg **page/**